# create new locale on centos 6

Tags: centos, locale, glibc, postgresql

Last Night there was power failure and the system was shutdown.

When system was stated in morning, PostgreSQL db server could not start.

While looking at the pgstartup.log file, following lines were found.

```
< 2017-01-23 15:26:17.577 IST >DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
< 2017-01-23 15:26:17.577 IST >HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.
```

It was clear that the locale required by PostgreSQL (en_US.UTF-8) was not available in system.

i have also cross verified by running locale command, here is the output.

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

while searching on internet i have found that i can create the missing locale using following command.

```
localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

However when i run that command it fails with following error:

```
$ sudo localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
[sudo] password for anil:
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:7: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:8: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:9: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:11: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:14: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:15: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:16: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:17: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:19: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:20: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:21: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:22: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:23: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:24: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:25: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:26: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:27: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:28: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:29: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:34: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:50: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1425: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1674: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1719: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1756: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:53: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:59: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:152: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:40: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1:3: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:10: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:11: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:12: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:13: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:14: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:15: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:16: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:17: non-symbolic character value should not be used
LC_NAME: field `name_gen' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `audience' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `application' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `abbreviation' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: no identification for category `LC_MEASUREMENT'
LC_CTYPE: table for class "upper": 1756 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "lower": 1756 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "alpha": 4320 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "digit": 600 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "xdigit": 600 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "space": 856 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "print": 5976 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "graph": 5976 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "blank": 856 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "cntrl": 664 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "punct": 4824 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "alnum": 4320 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "combining": 3152 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for class "combining_level3": 2832 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for map "toupper": 16924 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for map "tolower": 15388 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for map "totitle": 16924 bytes
LC_CTYPE: table for width: 26712 bytes
$
```

I have not found any solution for this error till now.

Env Details:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
```

All en_US Locales:

```
$ locale -a | grep en_US
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake I have done in following command:

---

Wrong command:

```
localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

---

Correct command:

```
localedef -v -c -i en_US -f utf8 en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: it's not correct solution. It gives me the following error ```character map file `utf8' not found: No such file or directory```